# Resx Translation does not work for menues

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I use the MvvmCross Resx Localization plugin. This works fine for all the layouts I have. But all the menues are untranslated. I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <group android:id="@+id/nav_items">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_accounts"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_balance"
      local:MvxLang="Text AccountsLabel" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_statistics"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_show_chart"
      local:MvxLang="Text StatisticsLabel" />
  </group>
  <group android:id="@+id/nav_footer">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_categories"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_label_outline"
      local:MvxLang="Text CategoriesLabel" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_backup"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_backup"
      local:MvxLang="Text BackupLabel" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
      local:MvxLang="Text BackupLabel" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_about"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
      local:MvxLang="Text AboutLabel" />
  </group>
</menu>
```

And I include it here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Menu"
    local:headerLayout="@layout/fragment_navigation_header"
    local:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer" />
```

Also I have the viewmodel with the TextSource definition:

```
    public IMvxLanguageBinder TextSource => new MvxLanguageBinder("", GetType().Name);
```

I made a constructor and resolved the label I want. For example "AboutLabel". This worked without any issues.
Is there a fix that the menu works as well ?

Comment: Menu items are not bindable.

Comment: ah, so there is no way avoid creating the translation via the android string file here?

Comment: You can either create them by hand, or translate them in OnPrepareOptionsMenu setting a title for each of them there

Comment: you mean creating the binding for the items by hand?